# Nginx как прокси к морде zabbix

Tags: nginx

Доброго времени суток всем!

К делу! Сервер zabbix - 10.0.0.2, сервер nginx - 10.0.0.3. Серверы zabbix и nginx установлены с нуля. Доступ к zabbix - 10.0.0.2/zabbix, при этом открывается первоначальная настройка zabbix (10.0.0.2/zabbix/setup.php).

Настраиваю nginx:

```
  listen 80;
  server_name zabbix;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.2/zabbix/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

В /etc/hosts добавил строку «10.0.0.3 zabbix».

При доступе в браузере к zabbix открывается zabbix/setup.php (стартовая страница первоначальных настроек). При нажатии на кнопку «next step» появляется вторая страница, но при нажатии на «next step» второй страницы открывается первая страница. Кнопки «next step» переключают первую и вторую страницы по кругу. Такое возможно победить или не возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, на сколько правильным является данное решение, но:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name zabbix;

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ /zabbix/ redirect;
}

    location /zabbix/ {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.2/zabbix/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```